# Проблема с отступом между flex блоками

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть такая разметка:

```css
.profile-v-container {
  margin-top: 15px;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -moz-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-align-items: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
}

.profile-v-b-no-p {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.profile-v-body {
  padding: 0 24px;
}

.profile-v-container>div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.flex-grow-1 {
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.profile-v-header {
  padding: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.block-md_ {
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.block-p_ {
  margin: 5px 20px;
}

.profile-v-b {
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  max-width: 530px;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-v-container flex">
  <div class="profile-v-b block-p_ block-md_ flex flex-grow-1" style="">
    <div class="profile-v-header">блок 1</div>
    <div class="profile-v-body">текст</div>
  </div>

  <div class="profile-v-b block-p_ profile-v-b-no-p block-md_ flex flex-grow-1" style="">
    <div class="profile-v-header">блок 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="profile-v-b block-p_ block-md_ flex flex-grow-1" style="">
    <div class="profile-v-header">блок 3</div>
    <div class="profile-v-body">текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст
      текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</div>
  </div>

  <div class="profile-v-b block-p_ block-md_ flex flex-grow-1" style="">
    <div class="profile-v-header">блок 4</div>
    <div class="profile-v-body">текст</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как уменьшить отступ между блоками 2 и 4, чтоб он был такого же размера, как между 1 и 3 блоками?

Comment: С сохранением структуры и порядка расположения блоков никак.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko а если сменить порядок?

Comment: @Артем если сделать `flex-direction: column`, то поменяется порядок, но будет как надо. @Yuri как раз дал ссылку на вопрос, где это применяется

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko если указать `column`, то все блоки будут строго вертикально друг за другом, а указать фиксированную ширину невозможно, потому что блок 4 может быть любых размеров.